Contiguous permutations
Is there a way to change this below OR have a different expression in order to get the results to be contiguous and forward:
Permutations[{1, 2, 3}, All]

{{}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}}

So I like to have as output:  (notice they are attached, hence 13 is not accepted, and they are not backwards: hence 32 or 321 are not accepted)
1, 2, 3, 12, 23, 123   

<== and joined into single numbers also as shown, not list members!
Another example would be:
{1,2,3,4} ==> 1,2,3,4,12,23,34,123,234,1234


how about fromSubsequences = Map[FromDigits]@*Rest@*Subsequences; fromSubsequences[list]?

Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't this the same as the "forward" part of this question?

@ydd is right. The solution under the linked question is fully applicable to this problem with minimal modification. Steve, please put a bit more effort in understanding the answers you've obtained, don't just use them blindly.

Update: after OP's comment
list = {7, 9, 6, 7};

FromDigits /@ 
 Flatten[Table[
   list[[m ;; n]], {m, Length[list]}, {n, m, Length[list]}], 1]


{7, 79, 796, 7967, 9, 96, 967, 6, 67, 7}

Or.
list = {7, 9, 6, 7};
Table[FromDigits@list[[m ;; m + n]], {n, 0, Length[list] - 1}, {m, 
   Length[list] - n}] // Flatten


{7, 9, 6, 7, 79, 96, 67, 796, 967, 7967}

Original answer.
If you do not accept 0 for an empty list {} use the second variant with Rest.
perm = Permutations[{1, 2, 3}, All];

FromDigits /@ 
 Select[perm, OrderedQ[#] && MatchQ[Differences[#], {1 ..} | {}] &]

FromDigits /@ 
  Select[perm, 
   OrderedQ[#] && MatchQ[Differences[#], {1 ..} | {}] &] // Rest


{0, 1, 2, 3, 12, 23, 123}

{1, 2, 3, 12, 23, 123}


Hi @azerbajdzan : plz check, does it work with this input:  {7, 9, 6, 7}   I think there are two 7s which throws out the calcs.   members are not distinct

@Steve237 For me it works. The output is {7, 9, 6, 67}. If you want them to be ordered just append //Sort at the end of the code.

The output should be:  7,9,6,7,79,96,67,796,967,7967   and dupes nicluded (ex: 7)

@Steve237 I assumed you wanted adjacent digits to be consecutive integers. I added another code.

Hi @azerbajdzan : what if the input was just a number? like 4225 - would the expression change that much to produce the same results?  Guess I can do this first?  First[RealDigits[4225]] ...then continue with your method?

@Steve237 Once again, please put a bit more effort in understanding the answers you've obtained, don't just use them blindly. You just need IntegerDigits, which already appears in these questions of yours: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A69429+integerdigits
